# "Excavator" badge's progress seems broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today I noticed that despite having several points in the [Archaeologist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist) badge (on Stack Overflow), I do not have the [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator) badge. To say more, Excavator was not even shown in the "Available" tab of popup "Select your next badge" (unfortunately I haven't made a screenshot proving it)

I tried searching for the badge in that popup, and after that it started showing. Now this popup looks like:

[image: screenshot]

(Also I tried editing one more old post: Archaeologist's progress increased, but nothing changed with Excavator).

So, my question is: am I missing something in these badges' requirements? Or does the progress for these 2 badges refresh at different frequences? Or is it a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug; https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/353919; there are multiple scheduled job for updating/awarding badges running at different intervals. It seemed like the badge was already awarded to you 15 minutes ago.

Comment: @abccd Indeed, it was. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: were you excavating badges?

Comment: @Luuklag Sorry, didn't get you?

Comment: Looks like you were specifically aiming to get this badge. No judgement.

Comment: @Luuklag No, I was not. If I were, I would try to get gold badges, not bronze ones :)

Comment: Even if someone was hunting those batches, it would only be a bad thing if one was editing without any purpose or to decrease the value of that answer / question. Anything else is a bonus to the site.

Comment: Badges are there to encourage good behavior, so go ahead and hunt those down!